# comparing BigDecimals

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I was working recently on one algorithm and I stumbled at one point where for example I have two java BigDecimals and their value are -1.9997 and -1.9989, BigDecimal's compareTo method considers -1.9989 greater than -1.9997, in this case I want them to be considered as equal, but if for example I have -1.9 and -1.86 I want them to be considered different. Is there a way to do it in Java?

Comment: *Why* do you want them to be equal? And *why* should the others not be equal?

Comment: Ok, I'll rephrase it: Why do you want to *consider* them equal.

Comment: Another equality relation that satisfies your requirements is `a.toString().length() == b.toString().length()`.

Answer (score 4):

Take the difference between the values and check it is smaller than some threshold/error e.g.

```
double x = -1.9997;
double y = -1.9989;
if(Math.abs(x - y) < 1e-3) // almost the same
```

Personally I would use `double` unless you need 15 or more digits of accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

Then you should *round* your numbers before comparing them. The default comparison is very reasonable.

```
BigDecimal price = x.scale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

This code rounds to two fractional digits.

Comment: The problem with rounding is that they can be almost the same but round differently. e.g. -1.99499 and -1.99500 rounded to 3 places would not be the same.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: That is conceivably what Rustam wants. He needs to specify more clearly what his idea of equality is.

Comment: I agree, there is not standard definition of "equal enough".

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan If you round to 4 then 3 then 2 places etc you move the problem to values like -1.994450 will round up and -1.994449 will round down.